# Update database and users can't access

Tags: database-design

When I update a database which users can access, users can see my update process.
I want let it be a model that users must access the old database when I'm updating the database.

I think a way is make a new database which I update it and synchronize it when I want let users access, is it correct? Or do I have to use another method to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: That's going to be **very much specific** to the particular, concrete **database system** you're using ..... I don't think there's any answer to this without defining what **concrete database system** you're interested in....

Comment: Put the database in administrative mode so noone can access while you perform updates? or must users be allowed to access system while updates are going on?  If updates are just data... wrap updates in transaction so that no updates are visible until all parts of transaction are complete?